# Angular 9/10: Display product data based on categories

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10

I have data from subscribe getAllProduct() to display in table:

```
[{
    "productId": 1,
    "name": "Stuart UC152 Magnetic Stirrer",
    "description": "Stuart UC152 Magnetic Stirrer, max. capacity 15L, Ceramic",
    "isTaxable": true,
    "sku": "UC512                                             ",
    "preferredVendor": "2",
    "pictures": "assets/img/product/magnetic_stirrer.jpg",
    "productGroupId": 3
},
{
    "productId": 2,
    "name": "Dell SE2419HR 24\" ",
    "description": "Dell SE2419HR 24\" Full HD IPS Monitor (HDMI, VGA, 3 Yrs Wrty)",
    "isTaxable": true,
    "sku": "DELL123                                           ",
    "preferredVendor": "1008",
    "pictures": "assets/img/product/lcd_monitor.jpg",
    "productGroupId": 4
},
{
    "productId": 3,
    "name": "Dell PowerEdge T140 Tower Server",
    "description": "Dell PowerEdge T140 Tower Server (E-2124, 8GB, 1TB, H330 Raid Controller)",
    "isTaxable": true,
    "sku": "T140                                              ",
    "preferredVendor": "1008",
    "pictures": "assets/img/product/server.jpg",
    "productGroupId": 4
},
{
    "productId": 4,
    "name": "Lab Binocular Compound Microscope ",
    "description": "AmScope 40X-2500X LED Lab Binocular Compound Microscope with 3D-Stage",
    "isTaxable": true,
    "sku": "DBN450                                            ",
    "preferredVendor": "1",
    "pictures": "assets/img/product/microscope.jpg",
    "productGroupId": 3
}]
```

The problem is when I try to display all the data into separate table based on productGroupId in one variable. You can see from the image that all product are mixed up, shown in both table and not separate based on productGroupId. Can anyone help me to understand how to make it display on separate table?

[image]

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Working on it. will share the stackblitz link later.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to separate the lists into two lists based on product group id

```
//Considering all your products are inside variable this.products
let labEquipments = this.products.filter(product => product.productGroupId == 3);
let itTools = this.products.filter(product => product.productGroupId == 4);
```

Then use these respective lists to display your tables

--Edit--

If you have a large number of product groups and get each list dynamically you can create a function for the same

```
getProductsByGroup(productGroupId){
    return this.products.filter(product => product.productGroupId == productGroupId);
}
```

Comment: then if the productGroup are being added more than it become more troublesome to declare for every categories of product